# What is this thermal adhesive? (heat transfer compound)

Tags: inverter, thermal, heatsink, heat-protection, glue

Well generally I I encounter this thermal adhesive. for example in inverter (brand: allen bradley). But it is different from I've seen before. It is very solid and generally using at very strange places, such as between 2 capacitors or at leads of a mosfet or top of capacitors block. Also it is very hard the repair a circuit, if that glue was used. Actually I cant find this stuff at store or web and I didnt understand why people use this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

this mine used. It is very liqued.

[image]

Comment: "*I encounter this thermal adhesive.*" By "thermal adhesive" do you mean "hot melt"? (Thermal adhesive could be understood to mean a thermally conductive adhesive such as used in heatsinking.) If you suspect that it is a hot melt then you might be able to soften it using a hot-air gun.

Comment: "do you mean "hot melt"?" yes. Also I ve added mine heat transfer compound. "soften it using a hot-air gun" I ve tried there is no change.

Comment: If it doesn't soften with heat then it's not hot-melt adhesive. There would be no need for thermally conductive adhesive on capacitors. It's just a glue to prevent component lead fatigue due to vibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks allot like a RTV silicone, such as DC744

This is for mechanical support. (In theory at least - not sure if the sloppy application here does any good)

Comment: OP says it's solid - which I understand to mean "hard". I don't think it's silicone.

Comment: DC744 gets quite hard, especially when aged. The messy and stringy application looks exactly like how DC744 would look if applied by someone without the proper tools.

Comment: Ah, OK. I've never come across that product name. The application is very sloppy.

Comment: I think this stuff https://www.dow.com/en-us/pdp.dowsil-744-rtv-adhesive-sealant.03321916h.html?tab=tds#pdp-overview

Answer (score 3):

this simply isn't thermal adhesive, and not a heat transfer compound. It's glue that's there for mechanical reasons!

(By the way, I would frown if someone glued over the emergency vents of my electrolytic capacitors like in your third picture. I'm pretty sure this specific way of gluing them to the vertical separator there does more harm than good.)

Answer (score 0):

See my other answers on Polyurethane adhesive. This is what is used, either 50 ShoreA for caps or >=70 Shore A for SMT joints.